# Multidimensional PHP array from a MySQLi table to HTML table

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array, mysqli

I have a portion of my website where I can give awards to members. Right now I am working on creating individual description pages for each award. On that page I want to include which members have already received this award and display this data in an HTML table.

I have already passed the data into a Multidimensional array as seen below.

```
<?php 

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $currentAward = $awardid; // Current Page Award. Local value to the page.

    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM vms_awardsgranted WHERE awardid='$currentAward'");

    $awardsList = array();
    while($pilotsList = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $awardsList[ $pilotsList["id"] ] = $pilotsList;
    }

    echo nl2br("DEBUG: $currentAward \n");
    print_r(array_values($awardsList));

    $conn->close();
?>
```

**Example Result**

```
DEBUG: 8 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 28 [awardid] => 8 [pilotid] => 4 [dateissued] => 2015-10-14 20:12:21 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 32 [awardid] => 8 [pilotid] => 1 [dateissued] => 2015-10-14 20:14:14 ) )
```

From here I am trying to parse this info and add it into the HTML table below but I honestly can't find the correct way of doing this with a Multidimensional array. Can anyone out here give me some insight? My HTML tables looks like below.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="ocean_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Pilot ID</th>
        <th>Pilot Name</th>
        <th>Date Awarded</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">

            </td>
            <td align="center">

            </td>
            <td align="center">

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, to loop through the result, your code could look like this:

```
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="ocean_table">
      <thead>
          <tr>
          <th>Pilot ID</th>
          <th>Pilot Name</th>
          <th>Date Awarded</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
  <?php foreach($awardsList as $member):?>    

          <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <?=$pilot['pilotid']?>
              </td>
              <td align="center">
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <?=$pilot['dateissued']?>
              </td>
          </tr>
  <?php endforeach;?>    

      </tbody>
  </table>
```

A couple of remarks, though.

- You don't return the pilot name from the query. You should join on the table of members/pilots to get their name.
- Your naming is confusing. `$pilotList` suggests a list of pilots, but instead that variable contains only the reference/junction between the award and one pilot. Dito for `awardsList` which actually contains a list of people that won the award.

Comment: Yeah, my variable names are honestly so muttled together right now. I had got lost in my page code and started mixing up variables.. Thanks for pointing that out. I will get that cleaned up now. **edit** thanks for noticing the lack of pilot name in my table.

Comment: This works perfect. But instead of just copying your code could you tell me exactly whats going on here so I can learn? I see that your passing each row of array data as $pilot, but what is actually happening there? Are you defining each row as $pilot and then are you querying each row via the <?=$pilot['pilotid']?> call and its finding pilotid in that row?

Comment: Er yes. Quite simply, the code contains a foreach loop that iterates over `$awardsList`. On each iteration the next item is made available in the variable `$pilot` (since  `awardsList` actually contains people, as I mentioned before). So that code just generates a table row for each item in that array. Then `<?=$pilot['pilotid']?>`. `<?=` is just a shorthand for `<?php echo `, so that code just echoes the values from `$pilot`. Apart from that it's just your code unmodified. The answer by @JulioSoares shows the same solution, only using a slightly different notation for the loop and the echo.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the extra time to explain. Rather then abusing this great service and just having people write stuff for me I actually have this burning passion to learn. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($awardsList as $record){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
              <?php echo $record['id']; ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
              <?php echo $record['awardid']; ?>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
              <?php echo $record['pilotid']; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```